# Raspberry Pi 4, weird problem: not booting, no display, ACT led constantly blinking

Tags: display, boot-issues

I was using my new Raspberry Pi 4 Model B 2GB with Ubuntu Server 20.04 for a week with no problems. After I cut the power for a short while, the raspberry would not boot all of a sudden.

I have:

- POWER (red) LED: solid
- ACT (green) LED: constantly rapid flashes without any pauses

**Note:** The green LED behavior does not change with or without SD card plugged in.

- No display output at all, even the UBoot screen

I tried:

- Putting my SD card into another raspberry (same model etc.): SD card works fine
- Removing the SD Card: no display at all (think I should've seen a Uboot screen or whatever)
- Flashed Raspbian and other OS on SD card: still no boot or display

Anyone has any idea about this situation? Maybe the raspberry is damaged somehow? I don't have any hot components on the board btw.

Comment: *"constantly rapid flashes"* -> Are these irregular, like they would be for the first few seconds after boot or when reading/writing a lot to the card?

Comment: No, the blinking is regular at high frequency e.g. 30 Hz.

Comment: Either the Pi does not detect the SD card, or you need to repair the BOOT EEPROM code.

Comment: I repaired the BOOT EEPROM code, nothing changed. I think there is something wrong with the board itself beyond reading the SD card, because I cannot see bootloader screen or boot from USB.

Comment: did you solve the problem? have the same wired beahaviour.